# javafx multiply stages and scenes (get or set controllers)

Tags: javafx

Im trying to launch multiply stages in one main. Here is what I got:

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoadera = new FXMLLoader();
                Controller controller = fxmlLoadera.getController();
                Parent roota = fxmlLoadera.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
                Stage stage=new Stage();
                stage.setTitle(start+""+i);
                stage.setScene(new Scene(roota, 630, 380));
                stage.show();
            }
```

But when Im trying to compile, Im getting plenty of errors. I tried to use loader.setcontroller but after that I cant access components from window.

Comment: As you currently have your code, the `fxmlLoadera.getController()` call will _always_ return `null`. When using `FXMLLoader` there is no controller until you either set one manually _before_ you call `load` (with `setController(Object)`) **or** you call one of the `load` methods and you have a `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file defined. If using the latter, _after_ you call `load` then `getController()` will return the controller instance that the `FXMLLoader` instantiated.

Comment: Also it needs to be one on the non-`static` load methods. Pass the location to the `FXMLLoader` constructor or use `setLocation`. However there's no obvious compile time error in your code. You need to add a better description of the error to the question.

Comment: Well, as you can read at my first post, I tried to use setController but Its not working. Setting controller and accessing it is doing nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986610/open-a-new-scenehas-its-own-controller-from-another-scenehas-its-own-controll      Answer of the question. Thanks for replies!